# Jquery: Hiding a div inside a hidden div with animation

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a `<div>` which is inside another `<div>` that is hidden. I am using an animation: `$("#innerDiv").hide(400)`, but as long as the outer `<div>` is hidden the inner `<div>` doesn't get hidden and is later visible when I unhide the outer `<div>`. If the outer `<div>` is shown, the inner `<div>` gets hidden with an animation as expected.

I don't expect the inner `<div>` to hide with an animation when the outer `<div>` is hidden since that wouldn't make sense. I would however expect that the `<div>` would at least become hidden, which isn't the case.

I found that changing the javascript to `$("#innerDiv").hide()` fixes the problem, but removes the animation that I would like to be there for when the outer `<div>` is visible.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aBqce/1/) is a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem. If you click the "Show" button first, then click the "Hide" button, the text disappears with an animation as I expect it to. However if you click the "Hide" button first, then click the "Show" button the text still appears. I expect it to be hidden (since I used the `.hide()` function.).

Why is this happening, and is there a way to keep the animation for when the outer `<div>` is visible, but make the `.hide(400)` actually hide the element when the outer `<div>` is hidden?

Comment: So, why you hide the parent `div` and not the `child div`?

Comment: Would http://jsfiddle.net/aBqce/2/ work for you?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann This is a part of a long form, and I am showing and hiding sections as the user goes. I want to hide the outer part until they get to that section, and depending on their previous choices I want the inner section to be hidden or shown.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy That's actually what I did originally while I was working on other things, but I noticed it didn't look as nice as if the inner section wasn't visible at all when the outer section was displayed. I moved my code around to hide the inner section before showing the outer, and ran into this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback option to manually change the inside div css `display` property to

`display : none`

[hide documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: Or, as this is required, to animate the inner div to hidden once the outer div is displayed. Or call `$("#outerDiv").show(400).find("#innerDiv").hide(400);` - this should hide the inner div as the outer div is being shown.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid adding a callback to do the hiding that the `.hide()` function should be doing. I came across [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5010) bug report from 3 years ago which seems to be the same problem I am having. They marked down the priority on it, and claim that this behavior is correct. There are a few suggestions on how to avoid it, but I'm not sure they're much better than using a callback. I think that may be my best option. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/aBqce/12/) a working example using a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a snippet to toggle the animation depending on if the parent is hidden:

```
var innerDiv = $("#innerDiv");
if(innerDiv .parents("div").is(":visible")){
    innerDiv.hide(400);
}else{
    innerDiv.hide();
}
```

**Edit: Explaining parents(...) selector further**

You could also use the .parents("...") call with any selector.  Thus if the nested div is deper than the immediate child it will still bubble up to find the targeted parent you want to check.  So if your parent div is named id="outerDiv" you could do:

```
$("#innerDiv").parents("#outerDiv").is(":visible")
```

**Edit: A more general workaround**

You could also do this for any element to determine whether it is hidden (You could write your own custom plugin for animate or just hide, but I'll leave that to you)

```
$(function(){
     HideOrAnimate($("#whatever"),400);
});

function HideOrAnimate(target, hideTime)
{
     if(target.parents(":hidden").length > 0){
          target.hide();
     }else{
          target.hide(hideTime);
     }
}
```

Comment: PS:  No callback needed for this solution.  You can make a plugin out of it if you so desire, but I'm a bit pressed for time... so the stand alone function will have to work for now.